# How to make a hyperlinkfield in asp.net c# read only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I need to enable a link that shows a .pdf document based on a parameter that comes from the datanavigateurlfield thats located in a folder in my project. I want to make the hyperlink "read only" or have it navigate back to the default webpage or even show a messagebox if there is no report in the folder for a specific cell a user clicks on in the gridview. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by read only hyper link, please clarify

Comment: What do you mean by "readonly" in respect to a hyperlinkfield

Comment: Not sure but I think what you are trying to say is "Disable" the hyperlink if there are no reports for hyperlink url, right? if yes then when you are binding the gridview and assigning url to hyperlink first check if that url has reports, if not then instead of hyperlink insert some message in particular cell. If you can explain exactly what you want then we can help you better.

Comment: I basically want to disable the hyperlinkfield based on if a certain parameter is not met. I can disable it, but the color goes to grey. Does anyone know a work around to this? Can you somehow make it read only? Or lock it?

Answer (score 1):

Use TemplateField instead of HyperLinkField:

```
<asp:TemplateField >
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
               NavigateUrl='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty((String)Eval("Url"))? "javascript: alert(\"no report\"); return false;" : Eval("Url") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to qualify the location that the link navigates to rather than anything fancy - in other words, perform this validation server-side.

For example, capture the DataRowBound (or equilivalent) event of your datagrid / container.  Obtain the dataitem and determine whether the URL is correct.  If it is and there's nothing to see here.  If it isn't, change the navigateUrl of the field to the appropriate location or JS code.